# Why not convex?

Tags: convex-optimization, matrix-decomposition

I am reading Nonnegative Matrix Factorization(NMF) and encounter following sentences:

> Although the functions $||V - W H||^2$ are convex in W only or H only, they are not convex in both variables together

Can someone explain why it's not convex in both variables together? Thanks.